# Written code in linear time as solution to dp problem but getting illogical answers

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I have written the following code to solve this [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/construct-the-array/problem) problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,k,x;
    cin>>n>>k>>x;
    double a,b;
    long int answer[n-1];
    if (x == 1)
        answer[1] = k-1;
    else 
        answer[1] = k-2;
    for (int i=3;i<=n-1;i++)
    {
        a = k-1;
        b = i-1;
        answer[i-1] = pow(a,b)-answer[i-2];
    }

    cout<<answer[n-2]<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

I have tried debugging it for hours and I find no inconsistency with my O(N) time solution. I am getting the same **negative** answer for large inputs of n,k,x: like `50 50 50`

I am not asking this for points but for educational purposes.

Comment: This looks like a good place to use a debugger. If you take a small input that produces an incorrect result error and step through the program with a debugger, monitoring the behaviour of every line, you should be able to spot when the program goes off the rails and starts producing incorrect results.

Comment: Take care when converting from `double` back to integer types. The results can get a bit weird because of imprecision inherent in floating point numbers.

Comment: Why has the question been downvoted? In my knowledge it is a reasonable question one would ask.

Comment: One reason for downvoting is it shows no signs of debugging other than *I have tried debugging it for hours*. For example, you have not provided an input dataset that produces the error you wish to have resolved. You can't do much debugging without a method for reproducing the error. Mahmood has pointed out one mistake. There may be more and the one he's pointed out might prove to not be the error you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of an overflow. Basically you are trying to store numbers that are too big for `int` to handle. You can use `long long` to store bigger numbers but even those have limit. I see the problem gives a number to use it as a mod. You can use that number to make sure your answer doesn't overflow by moding your answers over that number.

Comment: @RameshAgarwal It may be too late by then because the answer has long-since been destroyed. You have to protect the number from overflow at every step of the computation.

Comment: I don't see where you mod over 10^9 + 7. Also don't use the pow function. It gives unreliable results. Implement your own pow function.